# Asus Z170 motherboard stuck before boot

Tags: boot, motherboard, uefi

Yesterday my PC was working normally.

Today I pressed the power button to turn it on, but it freezes at

> Please press DEL or F2 to enter UEFI BIOS setting

The OS does not boot, and pressing any of these keys has no result so I can't access settings neither.

Restarting using the power or the reset buttons did not solve the problem.
My motherboard is an ASUS Z170 PRO GAMING.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I updated the BIOS to version 1904 some weeks ago.

It seemed to function normally until now, but has a bug: if you press the power button to turn the PC off just after the beep when you are restarting, when you turn it on again it will become stuck. For some reason this also happened when I turned it on normally.

Version 1805 seems to work well, so I downgraded.

I fixed it by opening the case by clearing RTC RAM as described in [the manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/Z170-PRO-GAMING/E10719_Z170_PRO_GAMING_UM_V2_WEB.pdf):

> [image]
>
> 1. Turn OFF the computer and unplug the power cord.
> 2. Use a metal object such as a screwdriver to short the two pins.
> 3. Plug the power cord and turn ON the computer.

I also had to remove the battery:

> If the steps above do not help, remove the onboard battery and short
>   the two pins  again to clear the CMOS RTC RAM data. After clearing the
>   CMOS, reinstall the battery.

When I turned it on, the "Please press DEL or F2 to enter UEFI BIOS setting" screen appeared for few seconds but then the motherboard asked me to enter setup to reenter data.

I booted normally, downloaded [version 1805](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/Z170-PRO-GAMING/Z170-PRO-GAMING-ASUS-1805.zip), entered BIOS settings and flashed that version using the ASUS EZ Flash 3 Utility in the Advanced Mode of the BIOS setup program.

Comment: Hi Oriol, I'm currently having the exact same problem and behaviour with my Z170 Pro Gaming mobo. I tried upgrading to the latest version (which is 2003 currently). So I also had the same reaction, no problem, I'll downgrade it back. But the utility tool wont let me. It says the previous bios file is not a correct BIOS. Did you have to do anything special to be able to downgrade the BIOS version?

Comment: @JensBrulmans No, nothing special, just choosing the older .CAP file worked fine. Currently I have version 2003, which for me doesn't seem to have this problem anymore

Comment: Thanks. The older file does not seem to be working for me. I get the message: "Selected file is not a proper BIOS!". It is like they locked downgrading or something. Can you confirm if you are still able to downgrade if you want? If you are not okay with that, I understand. But I think you wont be able to downgrade either, I think they patched it or something in one of the new BIOS versions. It's quite annoying because I am not able to boot anymore and I'm feeling a fresh BIOS install will do the trick. But I cant seem to override version 2003, because it just checks the version number

Comment: @JensBrulmans You are right, it seems version 2003 does not allow to downgrade. I got the "is not a proper BIOS" error for the 1805 and  1904 versions.